# Hardy Spaces - Proving that the norm is well defined

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hardy-spaces

I am self studying Banach Spaces of Analytic Function by Hoffman. In the Chapter 3 titled "Analytic and Harmonic Functions in the Unit Disc", the author defines the class $H^p$ for $1\le p \le \infty$ to be the class of analytic functions $f : \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ for which the functions $f_r : \mathbb T \to \mathbb C$ defined by $f_r (e^{it}) = f(re^{it})$ for $re^{it} \in \mathbb D$ are uniformly bounded in the $L^p$ norm for $0 \le r < 1$, that is, there is some $M > 0$  such that for every $r\in [0,1)$, $\lVert f_r \rVert _p < M$.

The author defines a norm on $H^p$ in the following way: $\lVert f \rVert = \lim_{r\to 1} \lVert f_r \rVert _p$.  It is not clear to me that the limit actually exists.

For $p= \infty$, I used the maximum modulus theorem for analytic functions to show that if $r_1 < r_2$ then $\lVert {f}_{r_1} \rVert _{\infty} \le \lVert {f}_{r_2} \rVert _ \infty$. Hence, the limit actually exists.

For $1 \le p < \infty$, I do not see how to prove it. Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: by the subharmonicity of $|f|^p, p>0$ for analytic functions the result follows immediately; note that $||f||_p$ exists for $0<p<1$ but it is not a norm anymore, just a (locally convex) metric on an infinitely dimensional vector space;  for Hardy spaces take a look in a specialized book like Duren's one on the subject first 3-4 chapters

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the response. The author does not introduce subharmonic functions though. I was looking for a proof that does not involve subharmonic functions.

Comment: Maybe just show that if $u$ is a harmonic function equal to $|f|^p$ on the circle of radius $R$ then $|f|^p \le u$ inside the circle by contradiction (using that $2\pi \epsilon |f|^p(z) \le \int_{C(z, \epsilon)} |f|^p$ for every $z$ and small enough $\epsilon$ and usual stuff about harmonic functions; for norm $2$ the result is obvious as norm $2$ is more or else a power series with positive coefficients in the radius, so another way would be to take $f^{2/p}$ with appropriate care at branches of zeroes; the subharmonicity of $\log |f|$ (Jensen theorem) is crucial for monotonicity

Comment: one can define Hardy spaces for harmonic functions using the supremum of the $p$ norms so that's another way to think of them - for harmonic functions monotonicity of $||u||_p$ in the radius doesn;t hold in general

Comment: @Conrad If it is the case that for harmonic functions the monotonicity of $\lVert u \rVert _p$ does not hold then it makes me wonder why the author skipped giving any details regarding the existence of the limit. Completely unrelated question: Do you have any textbook recommendations for studying $H^p$ spaces which is slightly an easier read and points out the subtleties?

Comment: Duren"s book is very good introduction - chapters $1-4$; as for the limit, this is a well known property of holomorphic functions as there is also a convexity property too; also monotonicity is not really essential as one can use the limsup as well